# How to compute good confidence intervals using knowledge about higher moments

Tags: confidence-interval, references

I have an algorithm which, given an input parameter $p\in \mathcal{P}$, runs through a (potentially very large) number of iterations before terminating. I want to approximate the probability (wrt some probability measure on $\mathcal{P}$) that the algorithm will terminate within the first $N$ iterations using the following (obvious) strategy: I sample $K$ parameters from my parameter space $\mathcal{P}$ and compute

$$X_K = \frac{\# \text{samples which terminated within $N$ iterations}}{K}$$

I want to determine a good confidence interval around $P(\text{algorithm terminates within $N$ iterations})$ to know how large I need to choose $K$ to be reasonably sure  the realization of $X_K$ will be a good estimate. Since the setting is quite general my idea was to use measure concentration inequalities (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality). This approach yields much better estimates if I can estimate the variance (or even higher moments) of $X_K$. I am thinking there must be an entire theory about how to do this correctly (most efficiently) in terms of numbers of samples. I.e. what's the lowest number of samples I must pick to get a really tight confidence interval? What I am really interested in is a reference to a book/paper/website where this is discussed in detail. Any comments are of course welcome and appreciated.